# WebView is not showing image

Tags: android

I have this website that is showing 'T-shirt' in browser and in other webviews etc, but I need it to be shown in this particular code. All others things are good except this image is not showing. So now I want it show this T-Shirt picture when the page is loaded.

MainActivity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       int count = 0;
       private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
       public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
       public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
       private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
       private int contador;
       private WebView webView;



       private ProgressBar progressBar;
       private ProgressBar progressBar2;
       private boolean firstTime;
       //private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        contador = 0;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
        //please leave it to me


        firstTime = true;

        if (checkConnectivity()) {

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            webView = new WebView(this);

            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);






          webView.getSettings().
          setLayoutAlgorithm(webView.getSettings().getLayoutAlgorithm().NORMAL);
            webView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
            webView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            }
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                      if (contador == 999) {
                       loadInterstitial();
                        contador = 0;
                       } else {
                          contador++;
                      }

                    progressBar2.setProgress(0);
                    progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;

                }                       //wait ok i try now again

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.web_url))
                            && firstTime) {
                        firstTime = false;

                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) 
              findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
                        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                       /* adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                            public void onAdLoaded() {
                                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);*/

                        FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                        fl.addView(webView);

                        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
                            {
                                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                i.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                            }


                            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devicesdo
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, 
         ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, 
         WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
                            {
                                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                                    uploadMessage = null;
                                }

                                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                                Intent intent = 
       fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                                try
                                {
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 
         REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                                {
                                    uploadMessage = null;
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    return false;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }

                            //For Android 4.1 only
                            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> 
       uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
                            {
                                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                                Intent intent = new 
      Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                intent.setType("image/*");

     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                            }

                            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
                            {
                                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                i.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,
                                                          int newProgress) {
                                progressBar2.setProgress(newProgress);
                                if (newProgress == 100) {
                                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            progressBar2
                                                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }, 0);

                                } else {
                                    progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }

            });

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);

                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.web_url));

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Please connect to internet and try again.");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Connection problem");
            dlgAlert.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dlg) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Retry",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                        }

                    });
            dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            finish();

                        }

                    });
            dlgAlert.create().show();

        }

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
            webView.goBack();
            count++;
            if (count == 999) {
            //    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    //mInterstitialAd.show();
              //      count=0;
                //}
            }
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

    }

    public void requestNewInterstitial() {
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        //mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void loadInterstitial() {
      //  if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        //    mInterstitialAd.show();
        //} else {
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}
    }
    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {


        int externalstoragepermission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int writesoragepermission=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        //]int readphonestatepermission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);


        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (externalstoragepermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (externalstoragepermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }


        /*if (camerapermission!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (readphonestatepermission!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
       */

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),111);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public boolean checkConnectivity() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (i == null)
            return false;
        if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
        if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    }
```

And my splash.xml is:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cargando"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreenimage" />



         <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

and main.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.khanzadakhan.pforpractice.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="gone" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is the web page responsive? share the url of the webpage whose image isn't being displayed in webview.

Comment: yes responsive: http://innovapp.solutions/android/disenadordecamisetas

Comment: this white shirt at the start is not showing in this code. i dont know why

Comment: @nandal reply??